# Boolean annotation resulting in duplicates?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-queryset, django-1.11

I am trying to implement a basic 'favourites' system based on a foreign key table.

Let's say I have the following simple models:

```
class Item(models.Model)
  id = models.IntegerField()

class User(models.Model)
  id = models.IntegerField()

class UserFavourites(models.Model)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='user_for_fav_rel')
  item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='item_for_fav_rel')
```

Now I generate the following queryset for items to see if they have been marked as a favourite by the user:

```
queryset = Item.objects.all()

USER_ID = request.user.id

queryset = queryset.annotate(
    favourite=Case(
        When(
            item_for_fav_rel__user__id=USER_ID,
            then=Value('True')
        ),
        default=Value('False'),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

All of this works great, but in the response, if the item has indeed been favourited, I receive a duplicate of that particular item in the queryset. Any idea how to avoid this?

Resultant SQL Query (edited down to the minimal example I think...)

```
SELECT 
    "core_item"."id", 
    CASE 
        WHEN "core_userfavourites"."user_id" = 1 THEN True 
        ELSE False 
    END AS "favourite" 
FROM "core_item" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN "core_userfavourites" 
    ON ("core_item"."id" = "core_userfavourites"."item_id")
```

Comment: What's the SQL query it generates?

Comment: See question edit...

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you use `all()` and then `annotate() `?

Comment: @sharette This is a small piece of a much larger program that uses django rest framework. I was trying to skim it down in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're getting one row for each combination of core_item and core_userfavorites. There doesn't seem to be a way to do exactly what you're trying without raw SQL, but fortunately Django very recently (1.11) added the ability to write SubQuery clauses which you can use here

```
from django.db.models.expressions import OuterRef, Subquery

queryset = Item.objects.all()

USER_ID = request.user.id
user_favorites = UserFavourites.objects.filter(
    user_id=USER_ID, 
    item_id=OuterRef('id')
)[:1].values('user_id')

queryset = queryset.annotate(user_favorite=Subquery(user_favorites))
```

This will give you the the `user_id` in the `user_favorite` field if the user has favorited it, `None` if they have not.

Basically you're writing a subquery to pick an arbitrary value from the related table.

Comment: Thanks Vinay! I'll try this out later tonight. Questions: Why are you slicing the subquery? Is this adaptable to a Boolean result?

Comment: A query will fail if the subquery returns more than one row. Might not be necessary in this case. You probably could turn this into a Boolean result by wrapping the subquery in a case like you had in your original expression. I'm not sure it's worth it though considering None will evaluate to False and other values of user_id will evaluate to True.  I'll admit it's a bit ugly though.  It would be nice if exists() could return a queryset or another chainable object instead of triggering execution and returning a value immediately.

Comment: Thanks again! This works great. I did manage to wrap it into True/False in the serializer for 'item' as part of Django Rest Framework.