# Django boolean annotate returning duplicates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, annotations, django-annotate

I have the following models:

```
class Institution(models.Model):
    pass

class Headquarter(models.Model):
    institution = models.ForeignKey(Institution, related_name='headquarters')

class Audit(models.Model):
    headquarter = models.ForeignKey(Headquarter, related_name='audits')
```

And the following query (basically, if an institution has at least one audit then has_visits must be true:

```
Institution.objects.annotate(
    has_visits=models.Case(
        models.When(headquarters__audits=None, then=False),
        default=True,
        output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )
 )
```

The problem is that if an institution has 2 audits then the queryset returns duplicate rows. I imagine it has something to do with the joins at the SQL level but I'm not sure how to correct it. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442937/boolean-annotation-resulting-in-duplicates) but I don't think OuterRef is what I'm looking for in my situation. What's the right way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Institution.objects.annotate(
    has_visits=Exists(
        Audit.objects.filter(headquarter__institution=OuterRef('pk'))
    )
)
```

Something else that could help is to let the duplicates "collapse", for example with a `Max`:

```
from django.db.models import Max, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Institution.objects.annotate(
    has_visits=Coalesce(Max(models.Case(
        models.When(headquarters__audits=None, then=False),
        default=True,
        output_field=models.BooleanField()
    )), Value(False))
)
```

but that likely makes it less readable and less efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For some extra context: I think this is related to a known and documented limitation (though the docs are easy to miss). The [docs on aggreation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations) have this section (copied from Django 4.2 docs):

> #### Combining multiple aggregations
>
> Combining multiple aggregations with annotate() will yield the wrong results because joins are used instead of subqueries:
>
> ```
> >>> book = Book.objects.first()
> >>> book.authors.count()
> 2
> >>> book.store_set.count()
> 3
> >>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors'), Count('store'))
> >>> q[0].authors__count
> 6
> >>> q[0].store__count
> 6
> ```
>
> For most aggregates, there is no way to avoid this problem, however, the Count aggregate has a distinct parameter that may help:
>
> ```
> >>> q = Book.objects.annotate(Count('authors', distinct=True), Count('store', distinct=True))
> >>> q[0].authors__count
> 2
> >>> q[0].store__count
> 3
> ```

This documentation is about aggregates that produce joins in an annotation, but I suspect essentially the same happens for annotations that produce a join by themselves, like the OP's example.

Another way to circumvent the limitation (though it might not be applicable to the OP's problem) is to put the aggregate in a subquery. I [previously explained](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:71) how to use the django-sql-utils package for this:

> For anyone else running into this, a reasonable workaround seems to be to use subqueries for aggregating annotations. This is a bit verbose/hacky in Django currently, as shown by the multitude of approaches in the stackoverflow link from [Antoine's comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:69). However, I've successfully used the [django-sql-utils package](https://github.com/martsberger/django-sql-utils) for this just now. That sounds a bit bulky, but it just has two utilities, one of which is a SubqueryAggregate class (with derived SubqueryCount, SubquerySum, etc.) that make converting a regular joining aggregate into a subquery aggregate easy and concise, without changing the structure much.
>
> For example taking the example from [comment 66](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060#comment:66) and converting the second annotation to a subquery with django-sql-utils, you'd get:
>
> ```
> Branch.objects.annotate(
>     total=Sum('center__client__loan__amount'),
>     repaid=SubquerySum('center__client__loan__payment_schedule__payments__principal'),
> )
> ```

There is also a [bug report tracking this limitation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10060). The OP's code is a bit more like [this bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25028), which was closed as a duplicate of the first one.